# mklink directory in wwwroot stops showing updated data after a few iterations of changes to files in the directory

Tags: windows, iis, symlink, mklink, wwwroot

On Windows 10 using IIS as the Web Server, it seems that directories created under wwwroot with the mklink command at some point stop seeing changes made to files in that directory.  The following is what I did to test this out:

I created a directory **C:\test** and then created a symlink to that directory on **C:\inetpub\wwwroot** using the following DOS command:

```
mklink /D C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test C:\test
```

Then, in the **C:\test** directory, I created a small HTML file called **test.html** with the following content:

```
<html>
<body>
This is test 1
</body>
</table>
```

Then, on the same computer, I open Microsoft Edge and go to the following page:

```
http://localhost/test/test.html
```

It works and displays **This is a test 1** as is expected.  Then I modify the file in Notepad to show **This is test 2**.  Again it works.  However, after a few iterations, in my case up to **This is test 5**, the browser stops showing the updated file.  It just shows **This is test 4**.  I can change the file to display numbers 6, 7, 8, etc, but the browser stays at **This is test 4**.

At first I thought it was a caching issue but I turned off caching in IIS and the problem persists.  I even rebooted after disabling caching and it starts working again for a few iterations and then stops updating again.

If you create directory **test** under **C:\inetpub\wwwroot** so **test** is NOT a symlink and go through the above exercise then it works perfectly, just like it is supposed to.

To get around this issue, I created a batch file **makelink.bat** with the following commands:

```
rmdir C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test
mklink /D C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test C:\test
timeout 300
makelink
```

This forces a recreation of the symlink every five minutes which causes the correct info to show up again in a browser for a few more iterations.  Obviously, this is not an ideal solution.

Is this a bug in Windows 10 or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Perhaps the modified time of the symlink folder is not updated so IIS does not bother reading the file again? NTFS can wait several minutes after a handle is closed before times are updated. Try Process Monitor...

Comment: Windows Explorer seems to show the updated time, but maybe IIS is not reading that time.  Regardless, I don't know what I need to do to make IIS see that the file is updated, even if that was case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable IIS caching in the registry, then reboot and try again.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\InetInfo\Parameters\DisableMemoryCache (REG_DWORD)
```

When this registry key is set to a nonzero value, the file cache is disabled, you can set it to 1.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  However, I disabled the cache and rebooted but it didn't make a difference.